# How to have Tooltip resize with Notebook magnification?

Tags: notebooks, options, style, tooltip

How do you make a `Tooltip` *label* expression change magnification when the `Notebook` magnification changes.  The *expr* of `Tooltip` changes magnification but not the *label*.

```
Tooltip[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}], 
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2 π}, ImageSize -> Tiny]
 , 
 TooltipStyle -> {Background -> White}
]
```

If you examine the size of tooltip plot as you change the notebook's magnification you will see that it never changes.  However, the main plot's size does change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why it isn't default but you have to put in a `TooltipStyle`:

```
Magnification -> FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
   EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]
```

`` FrontEnd` `` context is needed since it won't evaluate earlier and will be dynamically adjusted.

```
Tooltip[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}], 
  Column[{
    Dynamic@CurrentValue@Magnification, 
    Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2 π}, ImageSize -> Tiny]}], 
  TooltipStyle -> {
   Background -> White, 
   Magnification -> FrontEnd`AbsoluteCurrentValue[
     EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]
}]
```

[image]

---

You can put use it in Stylesheet too, as an option for `StyleData["TooltipLabel"]`.

Comment: Can you let me know If I change the `Magnification` using Window menu, where this `Magnification`  value stored? I checked `Options[$FrontEnd, Magnification]` before and after changing the `Magnification` but it is the same value (`{Magnification -> 1.}`)

Comment: @Algohi it is local to notebook: `Options[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification]`. Or `CurrentValue`.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks.